# Why is $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential-operators

i'm currently reading *An Introduction to Morse Theory* by Yukio Matsumoto and on p.62 it says

> A vector field itself is sort of a differential operator, since it
>   assigns to each point a "tangent vector" which is a differential
>   operation. Let us differentiate $f$ with respect to the gradient
>   vector field $X_f$:
>
> $$X_f \cdot f = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\cdot f = \sum_{i=1}^m \left(
>  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 \ge 0$$

I would love to understand why $$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\cdot f =  \left(
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)$$

Could anyone help me on this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just notation. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz's_notation) for a short description.

Comment: Thank you very much @soer9606. Can you also help me understanding what "differentiating $f$ with respect to the gradient vector field" means? Because all i see is just a product of $f$ with $X_f$.

Comment: @Zest I'm not completely at home with this, but I think that you can interpret it sort of like the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) (even though the gradient and the gradient vector field is not the same). Maybe you can see some similarities in the way that they are used. Especially notice that $\nabla \cdot f = \nabla f$ where $\nabla$ is the gradient, i.e. the gradient works sort of like an action on the function.

Comment: that helped! thank you very much :-)